# number of complex irreps

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Can irreducible complex representation of a finite group of be exhausted by

a) two 1-dimensional and two fifth-dimensional representations?

b) five  one-dimensional
and 1 five-dimensional?

My book says  "No. It can not (it is not possible)"

I tried. Let G be a finite group. Assume that it is possible. Then a) $|G|=1^2+1^2+5^2+5^2=52$ and $(G:G')=2. $

б) $|G|=1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+5^2=30$ and $(G:G′)=5$.

The problem is I can't find the contradiction.
I am sorry for me bad English. I am grateful for all corrections, comments and response.

Comment: There is no group $G$ of order $30$ with $|G'|=6$.

Comment: @Derek Holt Why?

Comment: Neither of the two types of groups of order $6$ has an automorphism of order $5$, so the group would be a direct product of groups of orders $5$ and $6$, but then we would not have $|G'|=6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a) use the result that the dimension of an irreducible representation divides the order of the group.